# Gray out the Background Making only Popup Visible

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

I want to have a popup where all the background is grayed out but I am not sure how to do it.

I found this on codepen ([http://codepen.io/adventuresinmissions/pen/nrhHF](http://bit.ly/1NDe103)) that does this (grays out the background when popup is opened). What makes it do that and how can I reproduce this?

I beleive it is somewhere in the css:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, main {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
html * {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #8f9cb5;
  background-color: #ffd88f;
}

a {
  color: #35a785;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */
.img-replace {
  /* replace text with an image */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xnugget info 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-nugget-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.cd-nugget-info a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5e6e8d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.no-touch .cd-nugget-info a:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
.cd-nugget-info span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cd-nugget-info span svg {
  display: block;
}
.cd-nugget-info .cd-nugget-info-arrow {
  fill: #5e6e8d;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */
header {
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5e6e8d;
  color: #FFF;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.cd-popup-trigger {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: #35a785;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-trigger {
    margin: 6em auto;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

xpopup 

-------------------------------- */
.cd-popup {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(94, 110, 141, 0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.cd-popup-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: .25em .25em .4em .4em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.cd-popup-container p {
  padding: 3em 1em;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  list-style: none;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons a {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a {
  background: #fc7169;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .25em;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: #fc8982;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a {
  background: #b6bece;
  border-radius: 0 0 .25em 0;
}
.no-touch .cd-popup-container .cd-buttons li:last-child a:hover {
  background-color: #c5ccd8;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before, .cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #8f9cb5;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 8px;
}
.cd-popup-container .cd-popup-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 8px;
}
.is-visible .cd-popup-container {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-popup-container {
    margin: 8em auto;
  }
}
```

Or in the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //open popup
    $('.cd-popup-trigger').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
    });

    //close popup
    $('.cd-popup').on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.cd-popup-close') || $(event.target).is('.cd-popup') ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
    //close popup when clicking the esc keyboard button
    $(document).keyup(function(event){
        if(event.which=='27'){
            $('.cd-popup').removeClass('is-visible');
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: What popup are you using?

Comment: Please show the code to your own popup and include at least an attempted solution to implement the gray background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fancybox.js and fancybox.css ,very simple,will eliminate complexities for you as seen in your code above

Demo/Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/

as simple as this

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
helpers : {
    overlay : {
        css : {
            'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)'
        }
     }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also include HTML because I can't see if you have extra "div" for this overlay.

If there's no "back-ground" div, you have to add one:

```
<div class="popup-background"></div>
```

Then add this part to your jQuery functions:

```
if($('.cd-popup').hasClass('is-visible')) {
     $('.popup-background').addClass('visible');
}
else if(!$('.cd-popup').hasClass('is-visible')) {
     $('.popup-background').removeClass('visible');
}
```

To CSS:

```
.popup-background {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: #fff; //whatever you want
     opacity: 0;
     transition: all 0.5 linear;
     -webkit-transition: same!
     -moz-transition: same!
     -o-transition: same!
}
.popup-background.visible {
     opacity: 1;
}
//This should be your pop-up container, this needs to have higher z-index in order to be obove background
.cd-popup {
   z-index: 9999;
}
```

UNTESTED & made with hurry - might contain mistakes. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.overlay {
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";       /*   IE 8 */
     filter: alpha(opacity=50);  /* IE 5-7 */
     -moz-opacity: 0.5;          /* Netscape */
     -khtml-opacity: 0.5;        /* Safari 1.x */
     opacity: 0.5; 
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     height:100%;
     width:100%
     background-color:grey;
     z-index:9998
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).append("<div class='overlay'></div>")
</script>
```

Make sure your popup has z-index of 9999